# Compare two strings and return matched values?

Tags: excel, vba, compare, match

I'm looking to compare two strings within two adjacent cells. 
All values separated by a comma. 
Returning the matched values separated by a comma.

Values are sometimes repeated more than once, and can be in different parts of the string. The largest string length in my list is 6264.

e.g.

```
Cell X2 = 219728401, 219728401, 219729021, 219734381, 219735301, 219739921

Cell Y2 = 229184121, 219728401, 219729021, 219734333, 216235302, 219735301

Result/Output = 219728401, 219729021, 219735301
```

The cells I would like to apply this to is not limited to only X2 and Y2, it would be columns X and Y, with output into column Z (or a column I can specify).

I appreciate any help with this, as my VBA knowledge is limited in Excel.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldyou consider parsing those two cells into 12?

Comment: My largest cell has A LOT of values, meaning two cells into 500+, I assume that could be a problem?

Comment: Check out the result now. Please accept if you think it works ok.

Comment: @JGFMK thank you, I have tried your code, it outputs matches into column Z, but it looks to be adding each row output to the next row. e.g. Row Z3, includes all matches plus, any matches found in Z2. Then Z4 includes any matches from Z2 and Z3, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another version that uses a Dictionary object to assess matches.

It also uses arrays to speed up the processing -- useful with large data sets.

Be sure to set a reference as noted in the comments of the code, but if you are going to be distributing this code, you may prefer to use late-binding.

One assumption is that all of your values are numeric.  If some include text, you may (or may not) want to change the dictionary comparemode to Text.

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub MatchUp()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, R As Range
    Dim V, W, X, Y, Z
    Dim D As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1") 'Change to your desired worksheet
With WS
    'Change `A` to `X` for your stated setup
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)

    'Read range into variant array
    V = R
End With

For I = 2 To UBound(V, 1)
    W = Split(V(I, 1), ",")
    X = Split(V(I, 2), ",")
    V(I, 3) = ""

    'Test and populate third column (in array) if there are matches
    'Will also eliminate any duplicate codes within the data columns
    Set D = New Dictionary
        For Each Y In W
            Y = Trim(Y) 'could be omitted if no leading/trailing spaces
            If Not D.Exists(Y) Then D.Add Y, Y
        Next Y
        For Each Z In X
            Z = Trim(Z)
            If D.Exists(Z) Then V(I, 3) = V(I, 3) & ", " & Z
        Next Z
    V(I, 3) = Mid(V(I, 3), 3)
Next I

R.EntireColumn.Clear
R.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"
R.Value = V 'write the results back to the worksheet, including column 3
R.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I have tried to run your solution however on the line (Dim D as Dictionary) I receive the error: "User-defined type not defined."

Comment: @Brooks You chose to NOT follow the instructions about either setting a reference or enabling late-binding. Had you done so, you would not see that error.

Answer (score 3):

If you now select a range of rows and run the macro - it will fill in Z column for each row selected based on X and Y column inputs.

```
Sub Macro1()
  ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732564/compare-two-strings-and-return-matched-values
  Dim XString       As String
  Dim YString       As String
  Dim XArray()      As String
  Dim YArray()      As String
  Dim xe            As Variant
  Dim ye            As Variant
  Dim res           As Variant
  Dim ZString       As String
  Dim resCollection As New Collection
  Dim XColumnNumber As Long
  Dim YColumnNumber As Long
  Dim ZColumnNumber As Long
  Dim found         As Boolean
  XColumnNumber = Range("X1").Column
  YColumnNumber = Range("Y1").Column ' Could have done XColumn + 1 ! But if you want F and H it will work too now.
  ZColumnNumber = Range("Z1").Column ' Your result goes here
  Set resCollection = Nothing
  For Each r In Selection.Rows
    XString = ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, XColumnNumber).Value
    YString = ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, YColumnNumber).Value
    Debug.Print "XString: "; XString
    Debug.Print "YString: "; YString
    XArray = Split(XString, ",")
    YArray = Split(YString, ",")
    For Each xe In XArray
      Debug.Print "xe:"; xe
      For Each ye In YArray
        Debug.Print "ye:"; ye
        If Trim(xe) = Trim(ye) Then
          Debug.Print "Same trimmed"
          found = False
          For Each res In resCollection
            If res = Trim(xe) Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
          Next res
          Debug.Print "Found: "; found
          If Not (found) Then
            resCollection.Add Trim(xe)
            Debug.Print "Adding: "; xe
          End If
        End If
      Next ye
    Next xe
    Debug.Print "resCollection: "; resCollection.Count
    ZString = ""
    For Each res In resCollection
        ZString = ZString & Trim(res) & ", "
    Next res
    If Len(ZString) > 2 Then
      ZString = Left(ZString, Len(ZString) - 2)
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, ZColumnNumber).Value = ZString
  Next r
End Sub
```

Note if you have 2,1,2 and 2,5,2 and want 2,2 then remove the if Not Found part and add each time.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've copied your code however I am getting a syntax error on lines: Dim X2Array    as Array and Dim Y2Array    as Array

Comment: Compile Error: Expected:New or type name

Comment: Dim X2Array    As Array & Dim Y2Array    As Array

Comment: Please note: The cells I would like to apply this to is not limited to only X2 and Y2, its rows X and Y, with output into column Z, if possible? The compare strings will always be in the same row.