# How to use a do-while loop to take the average of multiple arrays of data

Tags: excel, vba, loops, average, do-while

I am creating a program that analyzes a large amount of data quickly and efficiently. I have started the program, but I am stuck on how to create a loop of taking the average of each column in the data set and pasting the results on a new page. There are 64 different sets of data, each with 511 data entries. I also want to use the averageif function so that the zeros are ignored. I have seen so many references for an average loop, but I am fairly new to vba so I cannot interpret them well into my code.

The file named "Mu2e Program" is the main file, with all the code in module 1 that I have so far. The file named "FEB_histo_NT17290005_20181023_TRIAL_2" is the actual data being analyzed. In the code I have written already, it asks you to choose a file (in which I would choose "FEB_histo_..."), then it transposes the data and then adds the channel numbers on to a new page in the FEB file (later to be used to paste our averageif values). An example range used to find the average would be "D4:D515". I have a feeling that this is much more simple than I think, I just cannot figure it out! The most difficult part for me is understanding how to communicate to different workbooks (writing code on my program file that runs on the FEB file). It has been a long challenge!

```
Public Sub Start()
'to open and transpose the data
    Dim file As Variant
    Dim csvWb As Workbook, newWs As Worksheet
    Dim Mu2eWb As Workbook, Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyRange As Range

        file = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Report Files *.csv (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Please choose a .csv file to open", MultiSelect:=False)

        If file <> False Then
            Set csvWb = Workbooks.Open(file)
            Set Mu2eWb = ThisWorkbook
            Set copyRange = csvWb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
            Set Ws2 = Mu2eWb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Mu2eWb.Worksheets(Mu2eWb.Worksheets.Count))
        copyRange.Copy
            Ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
        End If

'to calculate and paste average on to a new worksheet (also label the channel columns)
    Dim AvgRange As Range
    Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim Col As Long

        Set Ws2 = ActiveSheet
        Set Cell = ActiveSheet.Range("D4")
        Set Cell = ActiveCell

        Set Ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))


    Ws3.Range("A1").Select
    Ws3.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("B1").Select
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("A1:B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:BL1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:BL1").Select

    With Workbooks("Mu2e Program.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")
        AVG = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("D:D"), 0)

    End With

End Sub
```

Right now, the only error that occurs is the last line of code, AVG = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("D:D"), 0). I don't really understand the error there, but regardless it will change since it will now be in a loop. I am really stuck and I hope someone can help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54736154/edit) to let us what the error on `AVG = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("D:D"), 0)` is?

Comment: 1, you do not tell us how/waht the various different ranges/data sets are. we do not know how to assist you in building your loop without having the information telling us where the other ranges/data sets are. 2, you are interacting with the application objects a bit too much - if you have larger amounts of data to process, working mostly in memory will give you a large performance boost. 3, you have a lot of undefined variables. You need to use option explicit to keep you from doing this - random nuissance errors can be avoided this way.

Comment: Surely in principal using `for each` is easier than `do - while`.

Comment: Nothing within the `With Workbooks("Mu2e Program.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")` block refers to the object specified in the With. Perhaps `AVG = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(.Range("D:D"), 0)` is what you meant? Putting the `.` in front of `Range` part means apply `.Range` to the object specified in the With block

Comment: Could you post a print screen of how data is arranged? Even a sample could help

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("D:D"),">0")`

Comment: Maybe you can cannibalise something out of this example I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732746/495157 ActiveSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = calc value. etc